# How to change Docker default port?

Tags: docker, port, otrs

I'm running OTRS using Docker.
But it uses a port 49154 /49153
May I know the command to change it to a fixed port?
Sorry. Thank you. Im new to docker.
By the way Im using CentOS.

Comment: Have you bothered doing a google search? The first one when I tried came up with https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/, which says: `Similarly, the Docker client can use -H to connect to a custom port.`

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand exactly what the problem is, as you haven't given many details. However, if you have done something like:

```
docker run -P -d otrs
```

Docker will be choosing a random high numbered port on the host for the container. You can bind to a specific port with the `-p` argument e.g:

```
docker run -p -d 8000:80 otrs
```

Will bind port 8000 on the host to port 80 in the container.